# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < using for loop in video js thumbnail

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

i  am using for loop to create thumbnail object array to shoe thumbnails on progress bar.But it gives the error of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"  at the for loop.Why it is giving this error?

here is the code

```
<script>
// initialize video.js
var video = videojs('video');
// here's an example of generating thumbnails from a sprited image:
var l=40; 
var t=60;
var c=0;
var tp=0;
var rt=80;
var bt=45;
var lt=0;
var i;
var j;
var op={};
video.thumbnails({
for(i=0,j=1;i<=95;i=i+5)
{
op[i]={src: 'M'+c+'.jpg',style: {left: '-'+l+'px',width: '800px',height: '90px',top: '-'+t+'px',clip: 'rect('+tp+'px,'+ rt+'px,'+ bt+'px,'+lt+ 'px)'}}
l=l+80;
rt=rt+80;
lt=lt+80;
if(j%10==0){t=t+45;rt=80;lt=0;l=40;}
if(j%100==0)
{t=60;c=c+1;
tp=0;rt=80;bt=45;lt=0;
}
j++;
}
)}
</script>
```

Also i want to create thumbnail object array like this.How can i do this dynamically or using loop etc?

```
/*
    0:{src: 'M0.jpg',style: {left: '-40px',width: '800px',height: '450px',top: '-60px',clip: 'rect(0, 80px, 45px, 0px)'}},
    5:{src: 'M0.jpg',style: {left: '-120px',width: '800px',height: '450px',top: '-60px',clip: 'rect(0, 160px, 45px, 80px)'}},
    10:{src: 'M0.jpg',style: {left: '-200px',width: '800px',height: '450px',top: '-60px',clip: 'rect(0, 240px, 45px, 160px)'}},
    15:{src: 'M0.jpg',style: {left: '-280px',width: '800px',height: '450px',top: '-60px',clip: 'rect(0, 320px, 45px, 240px)'}},
    20:{src: 'M0.jpg',style: {left: '-360px',width: '800px',height: '450px',top: '-60px',clip: 'rect(0, 400px, 45px, 320px)'}}*/
    });*/
```

Comment: I think the real cause of the issue is the previous line -

Comment: which previous line? Please answer in detail

Comment: Format your code, you'll see where the problem is - it looks like you're trying to pass an object parameter to video.thumbnails, but the object isn't an object, it's a block of code, which is not valid javascript syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you wanted, but this code doesn't have the errors:

```
var video = videojs('video');
// here's an example of generating thumbnails from a sprited image:
var l = 40;
var t = 60;
var c = 0;
var tp = 0;
var rt = 80;
var bt = 45;
var lt = 0;
var i;
var j;
var op = {};

video.thumbnails((function() {
    for (i = 0, j = 1; i <= 95; i = i + 5) {
      op[i] = {
        src: 'M' + c + '.jpg',
        style: {
          left: '-' + l + 'px',
          width: '800px',
          height: '90px',
          top: '-' + t + 'px',
          clip: 'rect(' + tp + 'px,' + rt + 'px,' + bt + 'px,' + lt + 'px)'
        }
      }
      l = l + 80;
      rt = rt + 80;
      lt = lt + 80;
      if (j % 10 == 0) {
        t = t + 45;
        rt = 80;
        lt = 0;
        l = 40;
      }
      if (j % 100 == 0) {
        t = 60;
        c = c + 1;
        tp = 0;
        rt = 80;
        bt = 45;
        lt = 0;
      }
      j++;
    }
  return op;
}()));
```

In your code the function thumbnails received invalid object, you can't put a for loop in the start of the object.